# Magento - Add custom Filter options (dropdown) for payment method

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I have a module that adds a **payment method** column to the Sales > Orders grid.

```
$this->addColumn('method', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment<br />Method'),
                'index' => 'method',
                'renderer'  => 'Artizara_Ordergridadditions_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Payment',
                'filter_index' => 'sfop.method', // refers to a declaration above
                type'  => 'options',
                'options' => array(0=>'Option 1',1=>'Option2'), // how would I get the keys to match to the renderer options???
        ));
```

Renderer code (below):

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());

    switch ($value) {
    case 'authorizenet':
        $value = 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)';
        $span = '';
        break;
    case 'paypal_express':
        $value = 'Paypal Express';
        $span = '';
        break;
    case 'checkmo':
        $value = 'Check/Money Order';
        $span = '';
        break;
    case 'free':
        $value = 'No Payment Required';
        $span = '';
        break;
    default:
        $value = 'Unknow Payment Method';
        $span = 'style="color:red;"';
    }

    return '<span ' . $span . '>' . $value . '</span>';
}
```

Simply want to be able to make a **dropdown prepopulated with the renderer options** for ***filtering*** in the grid.

**Note:** If I add the text field method for filtering, you have to put in the original keys from the database (e.g. - checkmo, paypal_express, authorizenet, etc).

I'd like to be able to show the renderer values for each in the dropdown...(how)?

**EDIT 7/20/12**

I've tried two following ways below but not working yet...

```
'options' => array(
                    array('value' => 'authorizenet', 'label' => 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)'),
                    array('value' => 'paypal_express', 'label' => 'Paypal Express'),
                    array('value' => 'checkmo', 'label' => 'Check/Money Order'),
                    array('value' => 'free', 'label' => 'No Payment Required'),
                ),
```

Just gets me a dropdown populated with 4 options as follows:

```
Array
Array
Array
Array
```

I've tried it also like this:

```
'options' => array(
                    array => ('value' => 'authorizenet', 'label' => 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)'),
                    array => ('value' => 'paypal_express', 'label' => 'Paypal Express'),
                    array => ('value' => 'checkmo', 'label' => 'Check/Money Order'),
                    array => ('value' => 'free', 'label' => 'No Payment Required'),
                ),
```

But I get an error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting '('`

Comment: Why are you manually defining payment methods in your renderer? Would be much better to make it dynamically load the payment methods in the system and use those.

Comment: I'm not manually defining them. I'm manually rendering the labels for them. Then I want to filter those results with a pre-populated dropdown in the orders grid...

Comment: Exactly, you are manually specifying the contents of the select box.  You could just be reading the config to get the same info dynamically.

Comment: Would you care to show me how? Or at least point towards a good tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an option hash with the values you use in your renderer :

```
'options' => array(
   'authorizenet' => 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)',
   [..]
)
```

On a side note, you may be interested by the `Enhanced Admin Grids` extension I develop ([page on Magento Connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html)), the latest version available on [github](https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids) has brought a custom columns system that allows to add new columns without rewrites and with quite some possibilities.
And as a basis, it comes with a payment method column for the orders grid.

Comment: 'options' => array(
                        array => ('value' => 'authorizenet', 'label' => 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)'),
                        array => ('value' => 'paypal_express', 'label' => 'Paypal Express'),
                        array => ('value' => 'checkmo', 'label' => 'Check/Money Order'),
                        array => ('value' => 'free', 'label' => 'No Payment Required'),
                    ),

This does not work for me...get an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting '('

Comment: 'options' => array(
                        array('value' => 'authorizenet', 'label' => 'Credit Card (Authorize.net)'),
                        array('value' => 'paypal_express', 'label' => 'Paypal Express'),
                        array('value' => 'checkmo', 'label' => 'Check/Money Order'),
                        array('value' => 'free', 'label' => 'No Payment Required'),
                    ),

This gives me the dropdown but it just gives "Array" as the options (Array, Array, Array, Array)

Comment: I've added the details above (formatted) so you & others can see it better

Comment: Sorry, confounded what the options filter await, use an option hash instead of an array, just like this : `'options' => array('autohorizenet' => 'Credit Card', [..])`. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow! It's always the one thing I didn't try (simpler solution). *Bangs head*. Need coffee or sleep or something. Thank you so much for setting me straight. Btw, I have tried (and very much like) your extension but won't work on our site b/c we're using a module that conflicts with yours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'       => Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentMethodList(true),
        'option_groups' => Mage::helper('payment')->getPaymentMethodList(true, true, true),
```

Answer (score 0):

visit 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/207929/

you may get the answer for your question.